# Footnote rule in beamer showing too early with overlays

Tags: beamer, footnotes, rules, overlays

Consider the following MWE :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item item
\item item\footnote<.->{footnote}
\item item
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The horizontal rule which is displayed between the main text and the footnote is showing on the first slide, although the footnote itself is uncovered only on the second slide.

Is there a way for this rule to be printed only with the footnote and not before?

Answer (score 4):

This rule is not part of the `\footnote` command but the frame with footnotes. It's drawn with `\footnoterule` command within `\beamer@autobreakframebox` in file `beamerbaseframesize.sty`. When beamer computes frame dimensions it considers if frame has footnotes and draws the rule in this case.

The best solution I can provide is not draw the rule at all. Next code includes a copy of 
`\beamer@autobreakframebox` in your file with a commented `\footnoterule` command. I don't know if this solution will work with other themes (I hope so).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@autobreakframebox{%
  \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\voidb@x%
  \ifbeamer@autobreak%
    % Ok, frame was overful -> split it!
    \setbox\@tempboxa=\vsplit\beamer@framebox to\beamer@autobreakfactor\textheight%
    \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\beamer@framebox%
    \@tempdima=\ht\beamer@splitbox%
    \ifdim\@tempdima<\beamer@autobreaklastheight%
      \global\beamer@autobreaklastheight=\@tempdima\relax%
    \else%
      \setbox\@tempboxa=\vbox{\unvbox\@tempboxa\unvbox\beamer@splitbox}%
      \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\voidb@x%
    \fi%
    \setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox to\textheight{\unvbox\@tempboxa%
      \vskip\beamer@framebottomskipautobreak%
      \ifvoid\beamer@splitbox%
        \ifvoid\beamer@footins%
        \else%
          \begingroup
            \usebeamercolor*[fg]{footnote}%
%            \footnoterule%
            \unvbox \beamer@footins%
            \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
          \endgroup  
        \fi%
      \fi%
      \beamer@exitcode%
    }%
  \else%
    \setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox to\textheight{\unvbox\beamer@framebox%
      \vskip\beamer@framebottomskip%
      \ifvoid\beamer@footins%
      \else%
        \begingroup
          \usebeamercolor*[fg]{footnote}%
%         \footnoterule%
          \unvbox \beamer@footins%
          \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
        \endgroup 
      \fi%
      \beamer@exitcode}%
    \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
  \fi%
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}[]
\item<1-> item
\item<2-> {item\footnote<2->{footnote}}
\item<3-> item
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is about one year ago but I just encounter the same problem now. The simplest way of disabling the `footnoterule` will be to redefine the `\footnoterule` command.

```
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
```

However, if you manage to disable the `\footnoterule` as in Ignasi's answer, you could use

**This method only added `\footnoterule` to your text instead of your footnote. A better workaround is added in the following paragraph**

```
\begin{frame}{frametitle}
My text\footnotemark[1]
...

\uncover<2>{\footnoterule}
\footnotetext[1]<2>{This is my footnote}
\end{frame}
```

which allows you to show the `\footnoterule` with your footnote in overlays.

**This method only added `\footnoterule` to your text instead of your footnote. A better workaround is added in the following paragraph**

A workaround is to remove the `\footnoterule` as in Ignasi's answer, and add the `\footnoterule` in the `defbeamertemplate*{footnote}` in `beamerinnertheme<themename>.sty`

```
% Footnotes

\defbeamertemplate*{footnote}{default}
{
\footnoterule\parindent 1em\noindent%
\raggedright
\hbox to 1.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}\insertfootnotetext\par%
}
```

This may not be found in `beamerinnertheme.sty` for all themes but you can always copy this definition from `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty` and modify it.

Comment: When I work on it, I realise there is some problem with my answer. The `uncover<2>{\footnoterule}` add the rule in the text instead of the footnote. 

A workaround has been identified and added to the answer.