# Beamer: how to make footnote rule appear later (pause)

Tags: beamer, formatting, footnotes, pause

I am using footnotes in `beamer` with the `pause` function. By default, footnotes appear as soon as the slide is created. Using the `<m-n>` function, I am able to make them appear at the correct time (i.e. when the sentence being footnoted appears).

However, the **footnote rule** still appears as soon as the slide is created. I would prefer it to appear exactly when the first footnote appears.

Here's a MWE. Note how the footnote rule is present in the first slide, while I would like it to appear in slide 3. An automatic solution would be ideal, but I am happy to do it manually if necessary.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \pause\item This sentence has no footnote
        \pause\item This sentence has the first footnote.\footnote<3->{hi there} The footnote rule should appear now.
        \pause\item Here's another footnote\footnote<4->{This is a footnote}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70666) appears to be very similar.

Comment: Oh, good catch - I couldn't find that. It didn't seem to get a satisfactory answer there, however

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can redefine `\footnoterule` to have the line be shown only on the slides you specify. In the example below, I put this part inside a `\bgroup`-`\egroup` pair to not affect the definition of `\footnoterule` on the other slides.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\bgroup
\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule
\def\footnoterule{\only<3->\oldfootnoterule}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \pause\item This sentence has no footnote
        \pause\item This sentence has the first footnote.\footnote<3->{hi there} The footnote rule should appear now.
        \pause\item Here's another footnote\footnote<4->{This is a footnote}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\egroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is a great quick fix for this problem, +1